# Unexpected semicolon?

Tags: php

Error log is throwing following error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in line 11`

Any idea why I'm getting this error ? As far as my knowledge of PHP goes all PHP statements ends with semicolon. What am I missing here ?

Providing full code as requested:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $firstName = $middleName = $lastName = $address = $mobileNumber = "";
    $password = $email = $result = "";      


    test_input($data) {

    $data = stripcslashes($data);     // <-- this is where error occurs
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    $data = htmlentities($data);

    return $data;
    }

    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","ilovemyself","eshop");
    if(!$link) {
        echo "Could not connect to the database !";
    } else {

        $firstName = test_input($_POST['firstName']);

    ...
    }
 }
```

Comment: kindly share the entire code to understand the error.

Comment: `test_input($data) {` is not valid, unless there's a "function" keyword before it?

Comment: You should have `test_input` outside of the `if` loop.

Comment: @Niet  You're right dammit ... I completely left out the function keyword. Kinda misleading though. Why it complains about semicolon ?

Comment: @MarkyMark Because it tries to evaluate `test_input($data)` as function **call** instead of a **definition**
 which would only be valid like `test_input($data);` if it finds further code.

Comment: @Xatenev Thank you for explanation !

Comment: @MilanChheda 1. `if` is no `loop` 2. It doesn't have to be outside of the `if`

Comment: Mark, do you realise having `htmlspecialchars` immediately followed by `htmlentities` will ruin your HTML code; because `"` becomes `&quot;` *then* becomes `&amp;quot;` which will not be understood by your HTML parser. Remove one of those two functions.

Comment: @Martin  Wow you're so right mate ! I just checked it on w3schools.com and they recommend using:
`function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}`

Comment: @Martin How can I upvote your suggestion ? It's really good and I just wanna appreciate it :)  I was going to sabotage my website without knowing.

Comment: You can tick the up arrow next to my comment. I would suggest **not** using W3fools and instead using the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or the [Mozilla Developers Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/PHP)

Comment: @Martin I don't see any arrows next to comments. I see arrows only next to Answers but not next to comments. Odd hm ...

Comment: Then you may not have enough reputation points to do that, yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are defining function in the wrong way.

Just replace your "test_input" block with this one:

```
    function test_input($data) {
        $data = stripcslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        $data = htmlentities($data);
        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: Yep. Already fixed it. You're sharing credit for a correct answer with @Niet The Dark Absol.

Comment: I have no idea why you rollbacked your version, even tho @NiettheDarkAbsol fixed your answer according to MCVE guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ah! i did it by mistake, have rolled back again :)